# Unable to pass mock verify

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I trying to test this end point:

```
[HttpPost("Register")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto>> RegisterUser([FromBody] RegisterDto registerDto)
{
    _logger.Info($"Register user end point hit. Username {registerDto.Username}");

    await validationService.Validate(registerDto);

    if (!await this.userService.CheckUserDoesNotAlreadyExistByName(registerDto.Username))
    {
        throw new ValidationException("Username already exists");
    }
    
    if(!await this.userService.CheckUserDoesNotAlreadyExistByEmail(registerDto.Email))
    {
        throw new ValidationException("Email already exists");
    }

    _logger.Info($"Register dto model validation complete. Attempting to create user. Username: {registerDto.Username}. Email: {registerDto.Email}");

    var newUser = this.mapper.Map<AppUser>(registerDto);

    var result = await this.userService.AttemptToCreateUser(newUser, registerDto.Password);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        AggregateException aggregateException = this.userService.HandleUnsuccessfulUserCreation(result.Errors);
        throw aggregateException;
    }
    else
    {
        return Ok(await this.userService.HandleSuccessfulUserCreation(newUser));
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to test specifically is the call to `this.userService.AttemptToCreateUser(newUser, registerDto.Password);`

This is the unit test I have setup:

```
[Fact]
public async void RegisterUser_should_call_user_service_AttemptToCreateUser_method()
{
    //arrange 
    var registerDto = MockRegisterDtoGenerator.GenerateMockRegisterDto();
    var appUser = MockUserGenerator.GenerateMockUser();
    var mockUserService = MockUserServiceGenerator.GenerateMockUserService(appUser);
    var sut = AccountControllerGenerator.CreateAccountController(mockUserService.Object);

    //Act 
    await sut.RegisterUser(registerDto);

    //assert
    mockUserService.Verify(x => x.AttemptToCreateUser(appUser, registerDto.Password), Times.Once);
}
```

This is the `GenerateMockUserService()` method:

```
internal static Mock<IUserService> GenerateMockUserService(AppUser mockUser)
{
    var userTask = Task.FromResult(mockUser);
    var mockUserService = new Mock<IUserService>();
    var identityResult = IdentityResult.Success;
    var identityResultTask = Task.FromResult(identityResult);
    mockUserService.Setup(x => x.UpdateUser(It.IsAny<AppUser>())).Returns(identityResultTask);
    mockUserService.Setup(x => x.AttemptToCreateUser(It.IsAny<AppUser>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(identityResultTask);
    mockUserService.Setup(x => x.FindByIdAsync(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(userTask);
    mockUserService.Setup(x => x.CheckUserDoesNotAlreadyExistByEmail(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(true));
    mockUserService.Setup(x => x.CheckUserDoesNotAlreadyExistByName(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(true));
    return mockUserService;
}
```

The test is failing with the following Message:

> Moq.MockException :  Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0
> times: x => x.AttemptToCreateUser(Mr Test, "Pa$$w0rd")
>
> Configured setups: x => x.AttemptToCreateUser(It.IsAny(),
> It.IsAny()), Times.Once
>
> Performed invocations:
> IUserService.CheckUserDoesNotAlreadyExistByName("Mr Test",
> System.Threading.CancellationToken)
> IUserService.CheckUserDoesNotAlreadyExistByEmail("TestEmail@gmail.com",
> System.Threading.CancellationToken)
> IUserService.AttemptToCreateUser(Mr Test, "Pa$$w0rd")
> IUserService.HandleSuccessfulUserCreation(Mr Test)

I'm finding this confusing as within the Performed invocations part of the failure message, it explicitly says that the method was called with the same arguments.

Does anyone know why this is failing?

Comment: Why did you declare your test method as `async void`? Please use `async Task` or `void`

Comment: Did you mock the `mapper` as well?